# Automatic logout from application without any movement in case of change password

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

Any user logins in my application with different-2 browsers or systems. And he wants to change the password. Once he'll change his password then he must be log-out from all browser's and systems automatically without any performing action and click.

Comment: You can do that with something like SignalR or WebSockets....

Comment: @Hackerman could you able to provide some references regarding the same.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: This sounds more like a request than a question?